# Не могу вызвать окно для обобщенного интерфейса ( Caliburn.Micro использование generic interface)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autofac, caliburn

Я пытаюсь сделать окно для отображения списка разных типов и не могу вызвать окно для обобщенного интерфейса.

Сам интерфейс:

```
public interface IItemsViewModel<T> : IScreen
{
    string Title { get; }
    T Item { get; set; }
    IList<T> Items { get; }
    void cmdAdd();
    void cmdDelete();
}
```

Его реализация:

```
public class CompaniesViewModel : Screen, IItemsViewModel<CompanyModel>
{
    private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;
    public CompaniesViewModel(ICompanyService companyService)
    {
        _companyService = companyService;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; } = "Компании";
    public CompanyModel Item { get; set; }
    public IList<CompanyModel> Items { get; private set; }

    public void cmdAdd(){}
    public void cmdDelete(){}
}
```

Вызов осуществляется:

```
var model = _scope.Resolve<IItemsViewModel<CompanyModel>>();

bool? result = _windowManager.ShowDialog(model);
```

Интерфейс связывается с помощью autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<CompaniesViewModel>().As<IItemsViewModel<CompanyModel>>();
```

Выводится ошибка, что не найдено view для CompaniesViewModel

Comment: проблема то в чем? Ошибка вылезает? Или не резолвится? Что конкретно работает не так, как должно?

Comment: Выводится ошибка, что не найдено view для CompaniesViewModel

Comment: А оно должно быть найдено? Я про view в вопросе тоже ничего не вижу.

Comment: До этого я резолвил интерфейс, правда необобщенный и работало без проблем, а с обобщенным не хочет

Comment: Погуглил этот фреймворк, в [доке](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/naming-conventions) нет ни слова про обобщенные типы, видимо, из коробки оно не поддерживается, надо шаманить

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26348530/312041)

Comment: Что делать - идете [сюда](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=caliburnmicro#), нажимаете на `issues`, потом поиском по странице находите `Add support for generic viewmodels` и разворачиваете обсуждение

Comment: второе что можно сделать - идете [туда же](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=caliburnmicro), нажимаете на `discussions`, ищете поиском по странице `CM Micro support for Generic ViewModels` - там есть пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге остановился на создании нового WindowManager с переопределенным методом:

```
public class GenericWindowsManager : WindowManager, IGenericWindowsManager
{
    protected override Window EnsureWindow(object model, object view, bool isDialog)
    {
        if (model.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType &&
                                                     x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IItemsViewModel<>)))
        {
            view = new ItemsView() as object;
        }

        return base.EnsureWindow(model, view, isDialog);
    }
}
```